# Replace call to scalar function with returned value in view definition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scalar function that looks something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_scalar_function
()
RETURNS uniqueidentifier
BEGIN
    RETURN '<GUID>'
END
```

I also have a view definition (with a bunch of joins) that calls this scalar function. The following is a representation of it:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM my_table
    WHERE Id = my_scalar_function()
```

I cannot change the scalar function to a TVF or anything else, and the GUID it contains is machine-specific. It is given that value during set-up and does not change afterwards.
The call to `my_scalar_function` is causing SQL to improperly optimize queries. If I manually replace the call with `<GUID>`, like so:

```
ALTER VIEW my_view AS
    SELECT Id, Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM my_table
    WHERE Id = '<GUID>'
```

then, the optimizations are proper.

So my question is, **how can I replace the call to scalar function with its result in the view definition, preferably at the time of creation, or alternatively, later with an** `ALTER VIEW` **query?**

Comment: Does it have to be a view? You could replace the view with a tvf.

Comment: Store the value in an object in the database and then you can filter to that. Don't modify the object definition after creation, per machine.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting bad plans with the query in your question but I assume your actual use case is more complicated. Nested views are especially problematic. for optimization. To answer your question, you could use a SQLCMD variable to specify the desired value during initial deployment (e.g. `WHERE Id = '$(MACHINE_GUID)'`)

Comment: @DanGuzman it is a complex nested view, indeed. This seems to be the best suggestion for me to try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your actual query plans and what is the desired query plan. It's a bit hard to troubleshoot.

However maybe this article can give you some insights:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5864/four-ways-to-improve-scalar-function-performance-in-sql-server/

Going with your example, to me it seems you do want to keep it as a function. Therefore using the WITH SCHEMABINDING option makes the function deterministic which can help the query optimizer.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_scalar_function
()
RETURNS uniqueidentifier
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN '<GUID>'
END
```

Schemabinding may also be used on the VIEW for potential improvements. But i think in this example the function not being seen as deterministic is the problem because the optimizer treats it differently.

Further reading/information:

http://www.sqlhammer.com/sql-server-schemabinding/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/05/12/improving-query-plans-with-the-schemabinding-option-on-t-sql-udfs/